# Can be used exist validator with a DynamicModel in Yii2

Tags: validation, model, yii2

I need validate a user input against a database, if the input exist, the field should be validate. I have created a Dynamic Model in this way:

```
$modelDynamic=new DynamicModel(['TIN','Business_Code']);
```

and added the next `exist` rule validator:

```
$modelDynamic->addRule('TIN','exist',[
                    'targetClass'=>'frontend\modules\profiles\models\PorfBusiness',
                    'targetAttribute'=>'TIN',
                    'skipOnEmpty'=>true
                    ])->validate();
```

all of them in my controller ProfPersonController.

And create this form in a view called profile:

```
if (isset($modelDynamic)) {

                $formDynamic = ActiveForm::begin([
                'type'=>ActiveForm::TYPE_HORIZONTAL,
                'formConfig'=>[],
                ]);
                echo $formDynamic->errorSummary($modelDynamic);

                echo $formDynamic->field($modelDynamic,'TIN')
                    ->textInput()
                    ->label(Yii::t('app','TIN'));

                echo $formDynamic->field($modelDynamic,'Business_Code')
                    ->textInput()
                    ->label(Yii::t('app','Business Code'));

                echo HTML::submitButton('Submit');

                ActiveForm::end();
            }
```

[image: Image with a wrong code]

(Imge with a wrong code)

The validation makes nothing, nor if the input is correct, nor if is incorrect. No errorSummary is sended neither.
Any error? Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Controller Code as

```
 $modelDynamic= new DynamicModel(['TIN','Business_Code']);

    $modelDynamic->addRule('TIN','exist',[
        'targetClass'=>'frontend\modules\profiles\models\PorfBusiness',
        'targetAttribute'=>'TIN',
        'skipOnEmpty' => true
    ]);

  if($modelDynamic->load(Yii::$app->request->post())&& $modelDynamic->validate()){
            //Model is Validated and ready to go throgh        
    }
```

You must validate() your model after `load()` of your `DynamicModel`